# Fluid 100% width showing large horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I can't figure this out - but I'm sure someone out there can...  I'm working on a new fluid width set to 100%, with min and max widths set for the content wrapper.

The problem arises when the header area isn't set to overflow:hidden - a large horizontal scroll appears, even though the margin is set to auto and there should be no overflow.  [Here's a link](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/coffee-break.html)

If any smart person could check it out with a fresh pair of eyes it would be a big help!  E.g. using Chrome inspector you could see the code, or I could post the CSS (currently inline until I assign the divs ids and classes)...

Answer (score 0):

4 divs under your header you have 3 divs that are relatively positioned... They have margins of more than 600 px, widths of 100%, and are positioned several hundred pixels from the left side... Removing these fixed the scroll issue but also deleted some of the header, will post screenie...

[image]

Give them proper widths this time...

Comment: Thank you both very much for your help

Comment: "Thanks" is all well and good, why don't you mark one of us answerer and give us points? Otherwise you're just a leach and people stop answering your questions...

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because of the two `div`s containing the birds on the header. The `div`s are block level elements, which means that they assume the width of their parents, and relatively positioned, so when they get moved, they push out of the containing `div`'s right and create the scrollbar. Here's what you see if you add a background to the two `div`s

[image]

The solution here is to simply assign both `div`s a width.

Comment: Thanks both very much - problem solved... Need to stop the late nights!

Comment: @Sue Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here, if an answer helped solve your problem, you should accept it by clicking on the green checkmark beside the answer. Doing so will mark your question as solved, and will give the answerer and asker a small reward for their trouble.

Comment: Still not quite there - I can't seem to fix the width of the birds, they keep setting the margin-right as 1194px! Don't suppose you have any other advice..?